# Relation Between 'testrpc', 'embark simulator', 'embark run development' and 'Intelij idea'

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, embark

I am very much confused on the relation between these four different stuffs (testrpc, embark simulator, embark run development, inellij idea ) . I have installed these all on Ubuntu . My question is how these are related to each other . There are different documents regarding these stuffs but I didn't found  understandable  relations on them .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I get it:

**testrpc** = it's a blockchain simulator where you can locally interact with your very own instance of etheruem without the need of mining and therefore paying fees (deploying contracts, calling them,...)

**embark simulator** = is afaik dependent on the testrpc (namely the ethereumjs-testrpc libraries), so all this command does, is starting the testrpc (blockchain simulator)

**embark run development** = this command will start the embark process:

1. connecting to the "development chain rpc" from the blockchain.json settings:

`"development": {
    "enabled": true,
    "networkType": "custom",
    "genesisBlock": "config/development/genesis.json",
    "datadir": ".embark/development/datadir",
    "mineWhenNeeded": true,
    "nodiscover": true,
    "maxpeers": 0,
    "rpcHost": "0.0.0.0",
    "rpcPort": 8545,
    "rpcCorsDomain": "http://localhost:8000",
    "account": {
      "password": "config/development/password"
    }`

2. deploying contracts and building contract objects (to later refer to them in JS)
3. preparing files for your webserver - based on embark.json it creates the dist folder
4. starting a web server according to the webserver.json settings

**inellij idea** = that would be your IDE settings

Hint: It should be clearer once you go through the embark demo:  [Embark documentation](http://embark.readthedocs.io/en/2.4.0/usage.html#usage-demo)